# Trouble with my if statements on ATM Machine

Tags: java

I am new to coding and I am in need of some help. I have tried this code for the last 3 days and I cannot get it to work, so any help is greatly appreciated. I am getting a lot of errors in the middle of the code and I am not sure why.

```
class Account extends JPanel    {
    public Account(ATMBuilder frame)    {
        guiBuilder = frame;

    static void setIsSavings()  {
        if(checkingRadio == checkingBtn)    {   
            isSavings= false;
        }else(checkingRadio == savingsBtn)  {
            isSavings =true;
        }
    }
}

Object command = e.getSource();
public void MyAccount(ATMBuilder frame) {
    double resultsCalc =0;
    double result = Math.round(result*1000000)/1000000;

        if(isSavings==false)    {
            resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
        }
        else if(isSavings==true)    {
            resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
        }
        else if (command == resetButton) {
            withdrawAmount.setText("");
            depositAmount.setText("");
            transferToAmount.setText("");
            balanceAmount.setText("");
            resultTxt.setText("");
        }
        else if (command == acceptButton) {
            try {
                fundsAvalable = Double.parseDouble(funds.getText());
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                    funds.setText("Invalid Amount of Funds");
                    return;
            }
        }
}
        //resultsCalc(funds);

    private void resultsCalc(double funds) {
        funds.setText(String.valueOf(funds));
        double amount = 0;
            try {
                amount = Double.parseDouble(withdarawAmount.getText());
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                funds.setText("Invalid Amount");
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, I am having some serious trouble with this. I need to make sure all withdraws are from either the checking or savings account. I continuously get the "not a statement" or "';' expected errors. The errors have been around the first and second if/ else if statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first two conditions will be hit; thus none of your other `else` blocks are entered. `isSavings` **must** be `true` ***or*** `false`.

Comment: Post your errors/exceptions so that we may try to help you out. Are you using an IDE in order to write/edit your code? There are certain statements and control flows which any decent IDE should warn you about, such as `double result = Math.round(result*1000000)/1000000;` (what are you trying to do there?) and the switch case Elliot Frisch has commented about.

Answer (score 0):

1 - First, you could adjust this method below to be shorter and more accurate:
From this:

```
static void setIsSavings()  {
  if(checkingRadio == checkingBtn)    {   
    isSavings= false;
  } else(checkingRadio == savingsBtn) {
    isSavings = true;
  }
}
```

To this:

```
static void setIsSavings() {
  isSavings = checkingRadio.equals(savingsBtn);
}
```

2 - Next, this block will cause you major problems in the flow:

```
if(isSavings==false)    {
  resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
} else if(isSavings==true) {
  resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
}
```

You should not compare boolean variables against false or true.
You could convert it to:

```
if(isSavings) {
  resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
} else {
  resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
}
```

Going a bit further, we can see that both if and else execute the same exact code, so we can get rid of the if/else structure entirely:

```
resultTxt.setText(String.valueof((int)Math.floor(result)));
```

Then, since you're comparing against false and true sequentially, none of the other elseifs will execute.
You probably should remove the word else from the line:
from:

```
else if (command == resetButton) {
```

to:

```
if (command == resetButton) {
```

Since we're at it, do not compare Objects that are not primitives with the == as that will not work in many situations. You can use the equals method for that:

```
if (command.equals(resetButton)) {
  ....
```

Last but not least, make sure to have a look at the Java style guide on how to format source code, I highly recommend the Google Java style guide. You can download an XML file that you can install on your IDE (Intellij or Eclipse) and it will automatically format the code for you every time you save the file.
https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html